# docker pull ignores http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables?

Tags: docker, proxy

It looks like `docker pull <image>` ignore the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables. I want to intercept the communication in order to better understand which HTTP requests `docker pull` performs - is there a way to look at them?

I'm executing docker pull on Ubuntu 18.

Answer (score 3):

at least in my case the solution above didn't work for me as my environment was [controlling docker with systemd](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/)

In summary:

1. Create a file named `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf`
2. Populate the file. Sample:

```
    [Service]
    Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80"
    Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.example.com:443"
    Environment="NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,docker-registry.example.com,.corp"
```

3. `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and `sudo systemctl restart docker`

Proxy specific information: https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy

Comment: side-note: only set "HTTP_PROXY" won't work for https registeries. docker daemon will directly access them(and failed for me) unless you  specify "HTTPS_PROXY". struggled hours to figure this out.

Answer (score -1):

You can configure the proxies in DockerClient.

On the Docker client, create or edit the file ~/.docker/config.json in the home directory of the user which starts containers.  Add JSON such as the following

```
{
 "proxies":
 {
   "default":
   {
     "httpProxy": "http://127.0.0.1:3001",
     "httpsProxy": "http://127.0.0.1:3001",
     "noProxy": "*.test.example.com,.example2.com"
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error you are facing? Probably worth restarting docker daemon. `sudo systemctl restart docker`

Comment: I'm not facing any error message, docker pull simply pulls the image without going through my proxy.

Comment: I just edited my comment. Restart the docker daemon

Comment: Ah yes, and I did restart the docker service after the configuration changes. Don't think it is strictly necessary as the docker cli tool reads the config file on each execution and the server is not taking part in the docker pull command, but for the sake of it, I tried it anyways.